# Python: Exit while loop by calling a function inside it

Tags: python-3.x

python

```
def insert_tuple2(word_list2):                                   
    while True:                                                     
        word_tuple = input("Write the word")
        if (word_tuple,) in word_list2:
            print("The word is alredy in the list!")
            menu_tuple(word_list2)

        else:
            description_tuple = input("Write its description")
            elsetuple = (word_tuple, description_tuple)
            word_list2 = word_list2 + [elsetuple]
            menu_tuple(word_list2)
```

The intention of the function is to ask for the `word_tuple` if `word_tuple` is already in the list the statement: `"The word is already in the list."` should be printed and the user should be asked for input in the menu function.

Alternatively `word_tuple` and `description_tuple` should be saved in `word_list2` and user back in the menu where the options are which calls various functions depending user input which is an integer.

1. for insert_tuple(word_list2)
2. for search_tuple(word_list2)
3. for exit_tuple(word_list2)

The problem is that the user gets asked about word and description inputs infinitely.

Comment: Please note that global variables are not allowed to be used in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ask for `input` infinitely because you use `while true:`

As I assume you may implement a menu driven program for user.

so below code may help you:

```
def insert_tuple2(word_list2):                                   
    word_tuple = input("Write the word")
    if (word_tuple,) in word_list2:
        print("The word is alredy in the list!")           
    else:
        description_tuple = input("Write its description")
        elsetuple = (word_tuple, description_tuple)
        word_list2 = word_list2 + [elsetuple]
    menu_tuple(word_list2)
```